# Vertical scrollbar for legend box

Tags: teechart

I'm using legend scrollbar tool in the teechart to show scrollbar for legend box. Now horizontal scroll bar is visible at bottom position but  I'm looking for a way to display a vertical scrollbar for legend box which in some cases could contain more than 50 legend items.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the legend scrollbar always is drawn in same position as legend alignment. But,  you can prevent possible problems in the cases where legend is aligned to bottom and contains a lot of legend items using the property MaxNumRow. The code below shows you how can do that

```
  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
        }
        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
            tChart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Steema.TeeChart.Tools.LegendScrollBar sclenged = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.LegendScrollBar(tChart1.Chart);
            for ( int i=0; i<50; i++)
            {
                new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine(tChart1.Chart);
                tChart1[i].FillSampleValues(10);
            }

            tChart1.Legend.Alignment = Steema.TeeChart.LegendAlignments.Bottom;
            tChart1.Legend.MaxNumRows = 3;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As described by Sandra, the TeeChart Legend places the scrollbar at the bottom of the Legend, horizontally, when aligned Top or Bottom of the Chart and on the right, vertically, when aligned to Left or Right. So an option for the vertical scroll is to position the Legend to the right of the Chart.

If you prefer the Legend at the bottom and you specifically require a vertical scrollbar, you can override the scrollbar location by custom setting the Legend position and dimensions. Note when overriding position, that the scrollbar horizontal or vertical behaviour will still respect the original Top/Bottom or Left/Right alignment of the Legend. Hence, for the Legend you want to achieve you can do something like this:

```
  tChart1.Legend.Alignment = Steema.TeeChart.LegendAlignments.Right;
  tChart1.Legend.CustomPosition = true; //Chart will now redimension, ignoring Legend location. Your responsibility now.
  tChart1.Panel.MarginBottom = 35; //make room. This is % .. can set as pixels, see MarginUnits
  tChart1.Legend.Left = tChart1.Axes.Left.Position; //lineup with Left Axis
  tChart1.Legend.Top = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Position + tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Size + 20; //make Top relative to Chart bottom axis location
  tChart1.Legend.AutoSize = false; //now set dimension you require
  tChart1.Legend.Width = 130; //your settings
  tChart1.Legend.Height = 70;
```

Downside is you’re not offered multiple columns with this approach (as the Legend still thinks it’s vertical); the previous suggestion (MaxNumRows on a bottom Legend) may still be more desirable.